# Why i am getting this errors even i have added my jar files in proguard-project.txt?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I just done with developement of Android application so now i want to release. For release i am using ant command line tool to build a release version of my `apk`.

I just executed the command `ant release` and got this Errors

> BUILD FAILED
>  /usr/src/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:679: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /usr/src/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:692: Compile failed;
>   see the compiler error output for details.

Apart of this i got lots of other errors like'

> [javac]
>   /root/workspace/Unit-Talk/src/org/sipchat/sipua/ui/ConnectionService.java:19:
>   package org.jivesoftware.smack.packet does not exist
>  [javac] import
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
>
> [javac]
>   /root/workspace/Unit-Talk/src/org/sipchat/sipua/ui/Sipdroid.java:89:
>   cannot find symbol
> [javac] symbol  : class PhoneNumber
> [javac]
>   location: class org.sipchat.sipua.ui.Sipdroid 
> [javac]     public
>   List invalidCases = new ArrayList();

All these error points to the class of jar file. Even i added the jars in proguard-project.txt

And yes if i am exporting the apk using eclipse then its working fine, i am not getting such errors. here is my [proguard-project.txt](http://pastie.org/5028284) file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from javac, at compilation time (before ProGuard is even started). You should make sure you have the proper libraries in the libs directory of your project.

Comment: the jar files are in my projects root directory,but i have configured this jars in java build path,so is that compulsory to put that jars under libs directory?

Comment: On the contrary: _don't_ add the ProGuard jar to your code, not by putting it in the libs directory or in any other way.

Comment: Thanks, i did that i got message of `BUILD SUCCESSFULLY`,but when i run the project my application is crashed and if i am signing my application using eclipse GUI then it worked properly. what should be the reason? i want to build my application using `ant release`

Comment: i didn't put proguard jar in my code,i am talking about external jar which i have used in my project